# Trying to get yacc code to compile

Tags: compiler-errors, bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to compile some code from a project that is no longer.  It contains some yacc/lex code.  I have tried compiling with yacc from bison, bison++ and bisonc++.  But none of them seem to be able to compile it.  I don't really know bison/yacc/lex, so any hints would be appreciated.

Here is the error message:

```
lex -t generator/parse_testvectors.l            \
    > generator/parse_testvectors.lex.c
yacc -o generator/parse_testvectors.C           \
    generator/parse_testvectors.y
generator/parse_testvectors.y:75.51-99: syntax error, unexpected {...}
generator/parse_testvectors.y:88.124-173: syntax error, unexpected {...}
generator/parse_testvectors.y:98.9-102.9: syntax error, unexpected {...}
generator/parse_testvectors.y:105.9-113.9: syntax error, unexpected {...}
generator/parse_testvectors.y:138.9-142.9: syntax error, unexpected {...}
...
```

Here is the code:

```
   ...
68 %token  MEMORY_KEYWORD
69 %token  STACK_KEYWORD
70 %token  STACK_TOP_KEYWORD
71 %token  FRAME_POINTER_KEYWORD
72
73 %%
74 main         :       testvector { i386_seq::num_testvectors = cur_testvector+1; }
75                          |       testvector main ; { i386_seq::num_testvectors =   cur_testvector+1; }
76
77 testvector               :       testvector_begin assignments testvector_end ;
78
79 assignments              :       register_assignments flag_assignments stack_assignment memory_assignment
80            {
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the `;` wrong - it should be after the code of the action, not before it.

Eg. here, the semicolon is misplaced:

```
testvector main ; { i386_seq::num_testvectors =   cur_testvector+1; }
----------------^
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!!! Thanks.  It's strange, because this code is supposed to work as is.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, psiphi75, you should mark it as the right answer.  Otherwise Stack Overflow users may refuse to answer your questions in the future.